# How to check why Windows/Boinc thinks computer is in use

Tags: windows-10

For some reason both BOINC and Windows 10 thinks that computer is in use even if I leave it overnight (no lock screen and no suspend). How can I check what exactly is keeping it 'busy'?

Comment: Normally, just remaining logged in will keep Windows, Linux in use.  Is that what is happening?

Comment: @John No, at least screen should be locked after some time of inactivity (30 minutes looking at settings).

Comment: Have you tried logging out as user?